# Java: Fill text area while scrolling (dynamic updates)

Tags: java, swing, dynamic

I have a very large array (0-64k) of memory values that I need to print to the window but the update time for this is very large.

Is it possible to update(print) the lines as the user scrolls?

I'm trying to avoid using custom buttons to call an update method and would like to use the built in scroll bars.

ps. I haven't used Swing much because my school provided a basic version so I apologize if I missed an easy way to accomplish this. I dont think any code I have at the moment would be helpful but let me know.

Comment: JTable and JList load their lines on demand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ignis is right about `JTable` and `JList`; both views use the [*flyweight pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) for [rendering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer). You'll also want to [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513) your code to see where any delays arise.